# How to code an artificial neural network (Tic-tac-toe)?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, neural-network, game-ai

I want to play Tic-tac-toe using an artificial neural network. My configuration for the network is as follows:
For each of the 9 fields, I use 2 input neuron. So I have 18 input neurons, of course. For every field, I have 1 input neuron for a piece of Player 1 and 1 neuron for a piece of Player 2. In addition to that, I have 1 output neuron which gives an evaluation of the current board position. The higher the output value is, the better is the position for Player 1. The lower it is, the better is it for Player 2.

But my problem is: How could I code that neural network? My idea was to use an Array[1-18] for the input neurons. The values of this array are the input weights. The I would walk through the array using a loop. Whenever there is a neuron to be activated, I add the weight to the output value. So the output value is the sum of the weights of the activated input neurons:

```
Output = SUM(ActivatedInputNeurons)
```

Do you think this is a good way of programming the network? Do you have better ideas?

I hope you can help me. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Well, you have an input layer of 18 neurons, and an output layer of 1 neuron.  That's OK.  However, you need to give your neural net the opportunity to put the inputs into relation.  For that, you need at least one intermediate layer.  I would propose to use 9 neurons in the intermediate layer.  Each of these should be connected to each input neuron, and the output neuron should be connected to each intermediate.  Each such connection has a weight, and each neuron has an activation level.

Then, you go through all neurons, a layer at a time.  The input layer is just activated with the board state.  For all further neurons, you go through all its respective connections and sum over the product of the connected neuron's activation level and the weight of the connection.  Finally, you calculate the activation level by applying a sigmoid function on this sum.

This is the working principle.  Now, you need to train this net to get better results.  There are several algorithms for this, you will have to do some googling and reading.  Finally, you might want to adjust the number of neurons and layers when the results don't get convincing fast enough.  For example, you could reduce the input layer to 9 neurons and activate them with +1 for an X and -1 for an O.  Perhaps adding another intermediate layer yields better results, or increasing the number of neurons of a layer.

Answer (score 5):

I don't particularly understand how you expect to get a meaningful summary of the board situation out of one output neuron.  I would more look at having:

```
    I I I             O O O
    I I I      x      O O O
    I I I             O O O
9 input neurons  9 output neurons
```

in a fully connected network, i.e. 81 weights.  Then train the output neurons for the relative desirability of playing in that position.

Comment: Bit of followup: I think you can use 9 input neurons instead of 18 because you can use 0 for "unoccupied", 1 for "self occupied" and -1 for "opponent occupied".

Comment: Only 9 inputs.... maybe. Using some hidden neurons, you'd surely be able to extract the needed information. Otherwise, an unoccupied field will be treated as the average of self occupied and opponent occupied, which sounds rather wrong. Nonetheless, for such a trivial game it may be good enough.

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at my Tic project. I've solved this problem with both neural network and genetic algorithm. The source code is freely available.

http://www.roncemer.com/tic-tac-toe-an-experiment-in-machine-learning

Answer (score 3):

I think you should implement a 'traditional' [feed-forward ANN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feedforward_neural_network) using transfer functions, as that allows you to train it using back-propagation. The code for these usually ends up being a few lines of code, something like this:

```
SetupInputs();
for (l = 1 .. layers.count)
    for (i = 0 .. layers[l].count)
        sum = 0
        for (j = 0 .. layers[l-1].count)
            sum += layers[l-1][j] * weights[l-1][j]
        layers[l][i] = TransferFunction(sum)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. But that would be a code for multilayer neural networks, wouldn't it?

Comment: Yes. You won't be able to calculate a usable score with just a perceptron (single layer). I did the same problem in university, and I couldn't train even a multi-layer network on tic-tac-toe using back-propagation.

Answer (score 0):

This is an excellent starter project for AI coding, but coming up with a complete solution will be way to big of an answer for SO.

As with most software, I recommend using an object-oriented design. For example: Define a `Neuron` class which has inputs, weights, and an output function. Then, create several of these `Neuron` objects in order to build your network.

See the wikipedia article on [artificial neural networks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_neural_network) for a good starting point.

Good luck with the code! Sounds like a lot of fun.

Answer (score 0):

After adding the weights, you need to normalize the sum using a function, people usually use TANH, if you want to allow negative numbers.

**edit:**

[Here is a java multilayer perceptron](https://jpicsort.dev.java.net/source/browse/jpicsort/src/evolutionary_nn/JavaMLP.java?rev=1.15&view=markup) implementation that i worked on a few years ago. this one was used for checkers, but with less inputs you can use it for checkers too.

Also, you need to probably figure out a way to teach it to win, but thats another problem

Comment: i cant update MY link, i have long deleted that repos. On the other hand, there are a bunch of implementations avaiable. this one looks decent to me: http://code.google.com/p/digitrecog/source/browse/trunk/src/backproped/JavaMLP.java?spec=svn44&r=44

Answer (score 0):

It is not a direct answer to your question, but you should have a look at the following framework/tool: [SNNS](http://www.ra.cs.uni-tuebingen.de/SNNS/) or its Java counterpart [JavaNNS](http://www.ra.cs.uni-tuebingen.de/downloads/JavaNNS/). I'm pretty sure that there you'll find an answer to your question.

Comment: Thanks! Both seem to be very good links. Unfortunately, I have neither C++ nor Java. I only have Delphi/Pascal.

Comment: You should be able to find examples on how things are done. Finally you want to learn or do smthg with ANNs, so the language is secondary, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

You will save time if you use neural network library like FANN or Neuroph.

One way to encode your input is by 9 input neurons. The output is also good to be 9 neurons. What I do not see in the other replays is the size of the hidden layer. I suppose you are going to use MLP with traditional 3 layers. The size of the hidden layer is always mystery. I would try 10 hidden neurons.

If the transfer function is sigmoid you can encode input as follows:

0.0 - O player.

1.0 - X player.

0.5 - Empty.

The output of the ANN will be 9 real numbers. In this case some of the cells will be occupied already. You can search for the highest output value which corresponds to an empty cell.